After upgrading to Next JS 12, @import in the .css file is ignored
I am working on existing project currently based on Next.js 11, and I am working to upgrade it to use Next.js 12.
The project uses CSS @import to load custom fonts.  However, with 12 the lines in the .css file are ignored -- to see the font, I have to add them into an the root level App component.
From style.css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat:wght@400;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kalam&display=swap');

The workaround - add it to the  tag in the main component.
      <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat:wght@400;700&display=swap'); @import
        url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kalam&display=swap');
      </style>

I assume this is because of the conversion from babel to SWC.  Is there some plugin/config I need to provide to SWC?  Or is the workaround the best option available?
